# Where do I change the due date for event invoices and can I set a fixed date instead of a variable date?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, invoice, dates

In our case, the invoices are being sent with each "pay later" event registration. The default appears to be 10 days. The client wants to change the date to September 3 of this year. Do I need a new invoice template? Can I do that? Can I do this somewhere in the Event setup for a set due date for all registrations?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Administer > CiviContribute > CiviContribute Component Settings that lets you change from the standard 10 days (you will need to tick the "enable tax and invoicing box to see it). But that doesn't get a fixed date. If you aren't using the invoices for something else then you could edit the "Contributions - Invoice" template in the "system workflow messages" tab in Administer > Communications > Message Templates.  Or if you do use the invoices for other things you could perhaps put some logic in the template to deal with the different cases. Hope that helps.

Comment: First, thanks! At least now I know where I need to go. The invoicing is a little tortured. This is a group of invoices for a specific event. I don't think we want to edit the message template permanently or even temporarily because other invoices are being processed,  unrelated to the event. Looks like I need to consider the logic option, but I really dread doing it. Coding is not one of my strengths.